# why cant I run rails generate inside a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Writing a gem and I need to generate a migration, but when I try I get the usage info

```
$ rails g migration AddSomeField
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
...
```

Comment: Run `pwd`. Are you in a directory containing a rails project?

Comment: i'm in the directory created by bundle gem, dont know if it's missing something for it to work, i didn't do rails new on it, but has a app, db, config, lib and others.

Comment: You shouldn't have those folders if this is a gem. A gem generally has lib, spec/test, docs, and make some things like public, or bin. But given that it's a library file, it won't have things like app, db, or config.

Comment: it's a gem for spree, it has overrides for views, models and controllers, that's why those are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have a script/rails not a config/application and that's why it's not working.